Electrical problem with front porch light not working
My electricity was shut off and the out side porch light was working so I screwed in a light fixture that has outlets on it and plugged in to many things and it stopped working I thought when the  electricity was back on it would work but no the breakers are fine and have power to the switch but not to the fixture out side any help would be greatly appreciated thanks.

Your power was shut off - by the power company or by flipping "all" the breakers off? You then screwed a light bulb socket to plug adapter in and proceeded to plug in too much stuff to the circuit and the breaker tripped, but now you can't find the tripped breaker? Have you turned the breaker for this circuit off, then back on? Sometimes they'll trip but the handle won't actually move...

What kind of home do you live in?   A single family house, a duplex, an apartment, an auxiliary dwelling unit on a private lot?  My first thought is you tripped a close neighbor's circuit breaker.  Or an outdoor lighting circuit that serves multiple residents.

If your power was shut off, and the light worked, then it wasn't powered by your power, so it's not on one of your breakers.

Please revise to punctuate your sentences properly. Show your volunteer helpers some respect by communicating clearly.  Also, did you mean "porch light was not working"?

Please address some of the questions raised in the comments, otherwise, will have to vote to close.

It is not a breaker and is a single family home was my grandparents sorry it took me such time to get back but I have been away for a long time and computers and all this is new to me and sorry my punctuation is not there thanks for your all feedback but I clearly should not have tried this computer stuff thanks for your time.


power to the switch but not to the fixture

Most likely problems are loose or damaged wire splices at the light, or at the switch.  So the first step is to remove the light and check for voltage at that end.  If there's none, then check the switch.
